# I3wm config randomly runs (or not) scripts

Tags: i3

In my i3 config file I have many scripts that I want to run when i3 starts, including a script to select a wallpaper and another to run polybar. Both of these scripts worked perfectly for more than a year, but suddenly they started behaving strangely: sometimes none of them run, sometimes just one of them run and sometimes only half of the script runs (wtf).

What I mean by only running half of the script is that, for example, polybar might kill all instances of polybar (first line) but not run my bar (second line), or the wal script might change the colors as intended, but not set the wallpaper.

All other scripts in the config run perfectly fine, except for these two. Running them individually in the terminal always works.

This is a part of .config/i3/config:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id /usr/bin/change-wallpaper
exec_always --no-startup-id $HOME/.config/polybar/launch.sh
```

This is change-wallpaper (I use pywal):

```
#!/bin/sh
files=(/home/marlon/Pictures/Wallpapers/*)
wal -i "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
```

And this is the script for launching polybar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
killall -q polybar
polybar bar1 >>/tmp/polybar1.log 2>&1 &
```

If I remove the change-wallpaper from the config, polybar runs perfectly fine all the time.

I have already tried using the full path, change the order, use only one script that does both of these things, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say, only half the script runs. Most likely, the parts that apparently don't run, they do actually run, but fail for some reason and you don't see the effect those commands normally have.

Programs generally write some kind of error messages in these cases. So this is mostly a debugging issue.
For polybar, you already redirect the output to a logfile at `/tmp/polybar1.log`. This file will most likely contain information about why the bar couldn't start.

I suggest you do the same for your pywal script to see why it fails to set the wallpaper.

Comment: When polybar fails to start, the only line in the log is:
`polybar|notice: Parsing config file: /home/marlon/.config/polybar/.config`

Comment: Hmm, normally, polybar will print at least one other message. The only way this doesn't happen is if it somehow exits in between. Your script does not capture messages produced if something like a segault happens. Try using `{ polybar bar1; } >>/tmp/polybar1.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: This is the other line it logs `/home/marlon/.config/polybar/launch.sh: line 10: 13240 User defined signal 1   polybar bar1`

Comment: Seems like something on your machine is sending the `SIGUSR1` signal to the polybar process before polybar has installed the signal handler, thus killing it.

Comment: Could it be pywal? Because when it doesn't run, polybar runs 100% of the time

Comment: What can I use to run these scripts instead of i3? Sometimes it might take a while for the wallpaper to change, so if I could run them before i3 it would be actually better than what I have now .

Comment: From the [pywal wiki](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal/wiki/Customization#polybar): "Polybar can read colors from Xresources to set the bar's colors. wal will also reload your config file for you automatically if it detects that polybar is running.". So, yeah it looks like pywal is the one doing this. I guess the solution is to not run the two scripts in parallel but only start polybar after pywal has run (or the other way around)

Comment: I see, but I actually don't know how do this, can you explain it to me?

Comment: You could call pywal from the polybar launch script or launch polybar from the change wallpaper script.

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! I've actually tried calling pywal from the polybar launch, and that didn't work. But the other way around actually works.